# While loop looking for unexpected input for no reason?

Tags: loops, input, while-loop

I am trying to run a while loop program that has nothing to do with input.  It is merely supposed to tell me what the final value of the calculation will be.  However when I run the program it does nothing.  It doesn't end either.  I am confused at what is happening?

```
int x = 90;
    while (x < 100)
    {
        x += 5;
        if (x > 95)
            x -= 25;
    }
    System.out.println( "final value for x is " + x);
```

Comment: It's ALWAYS in the loop, so it will never get to the println :) If you want to know if it works put the println in the loop.

Comment: What did you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 1):

The loop never terminates because `x` never reaches 100.  If you want to see for yourself what's happening to `x`, add a line to your loop so that the code looks like this:

```
int x = 90;
while (x < 100) {
    System.out.println("x = " + x);  // More useful output here...
    x += 5;
    if (x > 95)
        x -= 25;
}
System.out.println("final value for x is " + x);
```

Answer (score 0):

What happen is that your `while` loop is never stopping, so it never prints something, try changing your code inside the loop.

**How can you realize about that?**

Put some prints out and inside the `while` loop:

```
    int x = 90;
    System.out.println("Before the while");
    while (x < 100) {
        System.out.println("Inside the while");
        x += 5;
        if (x > 95)
            x -= 25;
    }
    System.out.println("final value for x is " + x);
```

Iteration 1:

```
x = 95
```

Iteration 2:

```
x = 100
if condition is true, so x = 75
```

... So whenever x reaches 100 the condition will make it 75. Therefore the while never ends.

Comment: I think that was my professor's intention.  He just wanted us to figure out what the result was.  I just wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing anything wrong with my execution.